# C# dynamic arry in attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

hi I need dynamic array in attribute in c#

for example:

```
 public class MyHtmlAttributesAttribute : System.Attribute
 {
    private IDictionary<string, string> Attrib { get; set; }
    public MyHtmlAttributesAttribute()
    {
        Attrib = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
    public MyHtmlAttributesAttribute(params string[][] values)
        : this()
    {             
        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            if (item.Count() < 1)
                throw new Exception("bad length array");
            this.Attrib.Add(item[0].ToLower(), item[1]);
        }

    }
 }
```

but when I want use this attribute I get error :
Array initializers can only be used in a variable or field initializer. Try using a new expression instead

I use this attribute by this style:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{

    [Required]
    [MyHtmlAttributes(new string[][]{{"Class", "ltr"}, {"AutoCompleteType" , "Disabled"}})]
    public string Email { get; set; }
  ...
  ..
 }
```

thank you for answer

Comment: C# attribute values are limited to compile time constants and `typeof` operators. You can read in more detail at C# specification [17.1.3 Attribute parameter types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664615(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: I can [MyHtmlAttributes(new string[]...] but idont now cannot use string[][]!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the attribute in this case, but in the array initialization. `{{"Class", "ltr"}, {"AutoCompleteType" , "Disabled"}}` could be used in an array initializer, but not in a new[] expression.
With new expression: `new string[][] {new string[] { "Class", "ltr" }, new string[]{ "AutoCompleteType", "Disabled" } };`
But since `params` is used, the encapsulating new string[] can be omitted:

```
 [MyHtmlAttributes(new string[]{"Class", "ltr"}, new string[]{"AutoCompleteType" , "Disabled"})]
```

**The following is purely an alternative**

An alternative is to allow multiple instances of the attribute to be applied, and combine them when obtaining them.

To allow multiple attributes:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple=true)]
 public class MyHtmlAttributesAttribute : System.Attribute
```

Apply them as

```
    [MyHtmlAttributes("Class", "ltr")]
    [MyHtmlAttributes("AutoCompleteType", "Disabled")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

Of course the constructor and implementation of the attribute has to be altered to allow only a single attr-value pair, but adding/removing a pair should only be easier this way. Combining them by reading all the MyHtmlAttributes instances on a property should be straight forward enough.

Comment: Note, that you'll have multiple instances of `MyHtmlAttributes` with no shared data.

Comment: very thanks answer but when use first style code:[MyHtmlAttributes(new string[]{"Class", "ltr"}, new string[]{"... i get error : An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type